# Database size is 10x bigger after import to mssql from sqllite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sql-server-2008

After import sqllite database (2.5GB) with odbc driver to mssql database now it takes 30GB. Log file is ok (I have simple recovery model) but main file is huge. Default datatypes for all columns where ntext, changing it to nvarchar just make it worse. 
Question is, is this normal?? Can it be made smaller?

Comment: You can check the individual file size of the databases by sp_helpfile. That might give some clarity. If not you can also check the individual size of the tables. Let us know your findings.

Comment: Have you checked that the import routine hasn't added white space to the columns?

Comment: Did your varchars become space-padded to fill the entire size of a column? Is there allocated unused space for the new tables? Is the character set the same between both the old and new databases?

Comment: Sorry I didn't answer for so long. I checked database files and only data file is big, log file is ok. columns are filled in proper way, it doesn't  seem that they have some spaces or white character (chcecked with len and datalength functions). numer of records is the same on both.  I used ODBC driver for this import, so maybe this may be some tip.